# How do I call a matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ satisfying $A^*A=\mathbf{1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

How do I call a matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ satisfying $A^*A=\mathbf{1}$? Maybe orthogonal?

Also I'd like to confirm that the following equivalences are true:

> Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$. Suppose that
> $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_k $ is the canonical internal product in
> $\mathbb{C}^k$ for $k=m,n$. Then the following propositions are
> equivalent:
>
> 1. $A^*A=\mathbf{1}$
> 2. $\Vert Ax\Vert =\Vert x\Vert $ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$
> 3. $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle_m  =\langle x,y\rangle _n$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^n$
> 4. The columns of $A$ are orthonormal.

Comment: One possible term for a matrix like this is [semiorthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix)

Comment: I've also heard the more specific terminology "isometric matrix"